# Rails join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Rails 5.2

I have a join table offers_users

```
class Offer < ApplicationRecord
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

class User < ApplicationRecord
has_and_belongs_to_many :offers
```

how can I get all users at a given offer.id?

```
@offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
@users = User.joins(:offers).where(id: @offer.id)
```

gives me only the first value. Thanks for support.

Comment: It's not `@users = @offer.users`?

Comment: `User.joins(:offers).where(id: @offer.id)` - this isn't right because it takes `@offer`'s `id` and tries to find users with this `id`. You joined `:offers` but didn't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `offer_id` it's simply:

```
users = Offer.find(offer_id).users
```

Optionally, here's solution that will produce one sql query instead of two:

```
users = User.joins(:offers).where(offers: { id: offer_id })
```

I recommend you to read [these guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference) for more info.

Comment: Thanks all..this really helpful